# Select the first row of each group after 'groupby()' and 'value_counts() function

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-science, data-analysis

I have a data set named `new_data_set` which looks like this:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2o22.png)

I want to find genre which came the maximum number of times for each year.

So I did this:

```
new_data_set.groupby('release_year')['genre']).apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())`
```

And the result of it looks like this:[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Glkw.png)

Now I am in need to fetch the first row from each group to get the answer. So the result should look like this:

```
1960 Drama
1961 Drama
.
.
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `index[0]` and then [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
new_data_set = pd.DataFrame({
         'release_year':[2004,2005,2004,2005,2005,2004],
         'genre':list('aaabbb')
})

df = (new_data_set.groupby('release_year')['genre']
                  .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
                  .reset_index()
                 )
print (df)
   release_year genre
0          2004     a
1          2005     b
```

Answer (score 1):

Lot of solutions, one is just to add the function head:

```
result = (new_data_set.groupby('release_year')['genre']
                    .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(1))
                    .reset_index())
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

For one line fans:

```
df = new_data_set.mode()
df

    release_year    genre
0   2004            a
1   2005            b
```